# Prevent opening file if macros not enabled

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet-protection

I did a workbook_open event that shows an input box to enter a specific password (each password opens a certain part of the file).

However, I have a problem that if the user doesn't enable the macro, he can see all the information in the file.

I'm looking for a way to prevent the user from reading or using the file if he doesn't enable the macro.

Comment: The only way you can really handle this is to hide the worksheets before close, and have your code unhide them if the password is entered correctly.  Eg. https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-excel-macros/

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to protect Excel spreadsheets and this VBA code will remove the protection:

```
Workbooks("salary ").Worksheets("data").UnProtect Password:="xyz"
```

A password is not good enough protection for your file:
[Decoding a password that protects an Excel file](https://victoriavette.com/iw/3342-how-to-unprotect-a-microsoft-excel-sheet.html) (the site is not in English).